Which かなう is it in「自らの利権にかなう」?

今回の騒ぎを起こした君！君はこのバッシングで現政権の信頼を失墜させ、自らの利権にかなう、新たな政権を擁立しようと計画しているんだろうが (YouTube clip)

I am not sure what this かなう here is. Is it the same かなう as in 「理にかなう」 which would fall under definition 1 「条件・基準などによく当てはまる。ぴったり合う。適合する。」 in this dictionary entry. But in the context it seems to mean something along the lines of 狙う or 図る. Definition 2 「思いどおりに実現する。願っていたことがそのとおりになる。」, which corresponds to 「叶う」, doesn't seem to fit either because 狙う・図る aren't really 実現. Also 叶う would call for が instead of に, I think.

This is 適う in kanji and means 適合する, or "to match/meet/satisfy".
Note that 自らの利権にかなう is a relative clause that modifies 新たな政権, so it doesn't need to have the meaning of 狙う by itself.

君は自らの利権にかなう新たな政権を擁立しようと計画しているんだろうが
You're planning to establish a new administration that matches your own vested interests, but...

